# How to remove last character of string buffer in java?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

I have following code, I wanted to remove last appended character from `StringBuffer`:

```
StringBuffer Att = new StringBuffer();
BigDecimal qty = m_line.getMovementQty();
int MMqty = qty.intValue();
for (int i = 0; i < MMqty;i++){
    Att.append(m_masi.getSerNo(true)).append(",");
}
String Ser= Att.toString();
fieldSerNo.setText(Ser);
```

I want to remove " , " after last value come (After finishing the For loop)

Comment: psudo code `if i != 0: string =  ',' + string`

Comment: You could do `Att.deleteCharAt(Att.length()-1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't append it in the first place:

```
for (int i = 0; i < MMqty;i++){
    Att.append(m_masi.getSerNo(true));
    if (i + 1 < MMqty) Att.append(",");
}
```

Also, note that if you don't require the synchronization (which you don't appear to in this code), it may be better to use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 11):

For your concrete use case, consider the answer from @AndyTurner. Not processing data which will be discarded later on is, in most cases, the most efficient solution.

Otherwise, to answer your question,

> How to remove last character of string buffer in java?

you can simply adjust the length of the `StringBuffer` with [`StringBuffer.setLength()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#setLength(int)):

```
...
StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
buf.append("Hello World");
buf.setLength(buf.length() - 1);
System.err.println(buf);
...
```

Output:

```
Hello Worl
```

Note that this requires that at least one character is available in the `StringBuffer`, otherwise you will get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

If the given length is less than the current length, the `setLength` method essentially sets the `count` member of the `AbstractStringBuilder` class to the given new length. No other operations like character array copies are executed in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

Added below line to your existing code.

```
 Ser = Ser.substring(0, Ser.length()-1);
```

Complet code:

```
StringBuffer Att = new StringBuffer();
    BigDecimal qty = m_line.getMovementQty();
    int MMqty = qty.intValue();

    for(int i =0; i< MMqty;i++){


        Att.append(m_masi.getSerNo(true)).append(",");
    }   

    String Ser= Att.toString();
    Ser = Ser.substring(0, Ser.length()-1);
fieldSerNo.setText(Ser);
```

Answer (score 0):

Pls check this .

Why u want to remove the last appended character `,` do not append then ? if you are not using the character for further .

```
    for (int i = 0; i < MMqty-1;i++){
        Att.append(m_masi.getSerNo(true)).append(",");
    }
```